# nanopb (Protocol Buffers library) repeated sub-messages encode

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

we are using the [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) library as our Protocol Buffers library. We defined the following messages:

`simple.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message repField {
    required float x = 1;
    required float y = 2;
    required float z = 3;
}

message SimpleMessage {
    required float lucky_number = 1;
    repeated repField vector = 2;
}
```

with `simple.options`

```
SimpleMessage.vector        max_count:300
```

So we know the `repField` has a fixed size of 300 and thus defining it as such.

Parts of the generated one looks like:

`simple.pb.c`:

```
const pb_field_t repField_fields[4] = {
    PB_FIELD(  1, FLOAT   , REQUIRED, STATIC  , FIRST, repField, x, x, 0),
    PB_FIELD(  2, FLOAT   , REQUIRED, STATIC  , OTHER, repField, y, x, 0),
    PB_FIELD(  3, FLOAT   , REQUIRED, STATIC  , OTHER, repField, z, y, 0),
    PB_LAST_FIELD
};

const pb_field_t SimpleMessage_fields[3] = {
    PB_FIELD(  1, FLOAT   , REQUIRED, STATIC  , FIRST, SimpleMessage, lucky_number, lucky_number, 0),
    PB_FIELD(  2, MESSAGE , REPEATED, STATIC  , OTHER, SimpleMessage, vector, lucky_number, &repField_fields),
    PB_LAST_FIELD
};
```

and part of `simple.pb.h`:

```
/* Struct definitions */
typedef struct _repField {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
/* @@protoc_insertion_point(struct:repField) */
} repField;

typedef struct _SimpleMessage {
    float lucky_number;
    pb_size_t vector_count;
    repField vector[300];
/* @@protoc_insertion_point(struct:SimpleMessage) */
} SimpleMessage;
```

We try to encode the message by doing:

```
// Init message
SimpleMessage message = SimpleMessage_init_zero;    
pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

// Fill in message
[...]

// Encode message
status = pb_encode(&stream, SimpleMessage_fields, &message);

// stream.bytes_written is wrong!
```

But the `stream.bytes_written` is wrong which means it is not encoded correctly, although `status=1`.

[In the documentation](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/reference.html#pb-encode) for `pb_encode()` it says:

> [...] However, submessages must be serialized twice: first to
>   calculate their size and then to actually write them to output. This
>   causes some constraints for callback fields, which must return the
>   same data on every call.

But, we are not sure how to interpret this sentence - what steps to follow exactly to achieve this.

So our question is:

- What is the correct way to encode messages that contain fixed-size (repeated) submessages using the [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb) library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using callback fields here, so that quote doesn't matter for you. But if you were, it would just mean that in some situations your callback would be called multiple times.

Are you the same person as [on the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nanopb/OT4Kw3Siuio)? Your stack overflow question does not show it, but the person on the forum has a similar problem that appears to be due to not setting `vector_count`. Then it will remain as 0 length array. So try adding:

```
message.vector_count = 300;
```

In the future, please wait a few days before posting the same question in multiple places. It's a waste of volunteer time to answer the same question multiple times.